# how to reference the tail of a column in Excel?

Tags: excel, reference

I know I can use `A:A` to reference the whole of column A in Excel. Excluding A1, **can I refer to (A2, A3, A4, ...) in a similar fashion?**

I've tried `A2:A` and have searched the Microsoft help pages for an overview of range notations, or a documentation of the "`:`" range operator, but haven't found any that include even the `A:A` notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
OFFSET(A2,0,0,ROWS(A:A)-1,1)
```